# Checking if Model count changed using lambda do.end block with rspec in one line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I have the following test, that checks wether upon creation of task a new Task and TaskConnection(join table between users and tasks) are made. So far I check that with 2 lambda's and would like to do it in 1 line...

```
 68       it 'can create new task' do       
 69         lambda do
 70           lambda do
 71             post :create, :project_id => project,         
 72                           :task => valid_attributes
 73           end.should change(Task, :count).by(1)
 74         end.should change(TaskConnection, :count).by(1)                                                                                          
 75       end
```

Something like this... Is it possible?

```
 68       it 'can create new task' do       
 69         lambda do
 71           post :create, :project_id => project,         
 72                         :task => valid_attributes
 73         end.should change(Task && TaskConnection, :count).by(1 && 1)                                                                                         
 75       end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it quite as you suggested in your second example, but you could combine them like this:

```
it 'can create new task' do
  lambda do
    post(:create, :project_id => project, :task => valid_attributes)
  end.should (change(Task, :count).by(1) && change(TaskConnection, :count).by(1))
end
```

I don't really recommend this approach though. While it's concise, the errors that RSpec reports when there are failures don't tell you which expectation failed. It just says that one of them didn't change the way you thought it would.